# Bind to all interfaces for IPv4 and IPv6 in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I want to configure [haproxy](https://serverfault.com/tags/haproxy/info) to bind to a `tcp` as well as `tcp6` socket on all interfaces (i.e., `0.0.0.0:80` and `:::80`).

I was able to reach this goal with the following settings:

```
listen web
  bind :80 v4v6
  bind :::80 v6only
```

Is there any shorter way than this?

While I expect it to behave different, the `v4v6` keyword makes *haproxy* bind to a v4 socket only.

Comment: What about `bind :::80 v4v6`?

Comment: Actually, this works. Thanks! Can you file it as answer please so that I can give you credit?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To listen on the same port for IPv6 and IPv4, use this:

```
bind :::80 v4v6
```

Admittedly, this was an intuitive guess that appears to have been correct... but rather than just post a "lucky" guess as the answer, even though it works, it seems like I should justify it.

> the v4v6 keyword makes haproxy bind to a v4 socket only.

My first intuition was that it's not `v4v6` but rather the use of `:80` (or, more precisely, the use of no IP address at all, just a port number) that causes this socket to listen on IPv4 only.

This seems to be confirmed in the docs for `bind`:

> `address` is optional and can be a host name, an IPv4 address, an IPv6 address, or `'*'`. It designates the address the frontend will listen on. **If unset, all IPv4 addresses of the system will be-listened on. The same will apply for `'*'` or the system's special address "`0.0.0.0`".** The IPv6 equivalent is '::'.
>
> http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#4.2-bind (emphasis added)

So the following three forms are all equivalent, and are all interpreted as being IPv4 by HAProxy:

```
bind :80
bind *:80
bind 0.0.0.0:80
```

Next, there is one sentence in the docs for `v4v6` could be read in isolation to indicate that `v4v6` might be usable to extend one of the above bind statements to listen on IPv6...

> **v4v6**
>
> It is used to bind a socket to both IPv4 and IPv6 when it uses the default address.

...hmmm, but I suspect that this actually means "the v6 default address" (`::`)...

> Doing so is sometimes necessary
>   on systems which bind to IPv6 only by default.

...and now, I suspect it even more...

> It has no effect on non-IPv6
>   sockets, and is overridden by the `v6only` option.
>
> http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#5.1

So, it appears that `v4v6` only modifies `bind` directives that specify the IPv6 default listen address, which is `::` (the 3rd `:` is the separator between the address and the port), and is ignored for others.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer does not work for me, at least with haproxy-1.6.11p0 on OpenBSD. Also, TL;DR. Just do:

```
bind 0.0.0.0:80
bind :::80
```

and it will work:

```
# netstat -an|grep "*.80"
tcp          0      0  *.80                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6         0      0  *.80                   *.*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 4):

I know im late to the party. Im not allowed to comment so i had to add this answer.

I just wanted to add if you dont like the way the triple colons ::: look

```
bind :::80
```

You can always enclose IPv6 address in brackets.

```
bind [::]:80
```

Answer (score 1):

I configure it like this:

```
    bind *:80,[::]:80 v6only
    bind *:443,[::]:443 v6only ssl crt ...
```

Comment: The `v6only` part seems really counterintuitive this way, but is does seems to do the trick!